# High resolution bitmap quality issue after scaling

Tags: apache-flex, flex4.5, scaling, bitmapdata

In AIR application I am loading bitmap as BorderContainers background image with BitmapFillMode.SCALE. I am smoothing Bitmapdata.

original bitmap dimension: 5100 x 7014
scaling it to 595 x 841.

but background quality was lost.

any solutions?

actual image[image]

scaled Image [image]

any workarounds? Im using Flex 4.5

Comment: You could try to Pre-scale it in a tool such as Photoshop?  Isn't there a quality drop expected when scaling a bitmap?

Comment: @Reboog711 no, im setting background Image in runtime, user will browse and set background image.. user prefer high resolution image for 6x zooming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved : There is a limitation for bitmap resolution in Flashplayer earlier versions.

so I used Apache flex 4.9.1 sdk which supports flashplayer 11.1.

I used `spark.primitives.BitmapImage` and set `smoothingQuality=BitmapSmoothingQuality.HIGH`